# Excel VBA: how to store combo box current value to cell

Tags: excel, vba

For a Login Form, I use the below code to store the values of all textbox and combo box controls in a separate sheet, the tags and text box values are populated, however the combo box values alone do not get written to cells. Can anyone point out my mistake?

```
For Each cControl In frmLogin.Controls
If cControl.Name Like "txt*" Or cControl.Name Like "cb*" Then
    Sheet5.Cells(m, 10).Value = cControl.Tag
    Sheet5.Cells(m, 11).Value = cControl.Text
    m = m + 1
End If
```

Next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `MSForms` to do the comparison.

Try this

```
Dim cControl As Control
Dim m As Long

'~~> Change as applicable
m = 1

For Each cControl In frmLogin.Controls
    If TypeOf cControl Is MSForms.TextBox Or _
    TypeOf cControl Is MSForms.ComboBox Then
        Sheet5.Cells(m, 10).Value = cControl.Tag
        Sheet5.Cells(m, 11).Value = cControl.Text
        m = m + 1
    End If
Next
```